# How to remove lines from UV Map image?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have made a model and filled it with colour using colour from the material tab. I then unwrapped the model and exported it. The colours were there (perfect). However the edges had really annoying black lines which shows in my game. So how do I export the UV Map without the edge lines. Even better how to export a UV Map with the material colours

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you used the export UV layout operation to get the color information.

Instead,you can bake the diffuse texture to get the color in formation without edges,and make sure you have high margin :

[image: Margin]

Comment: I don't have Textures as a *Bake Mode* however I used *Diffuse Colour* and that worked fine. Thank you very much!!